# php language file windows-1255

Tags: php, file, encoding, lang

my language file is like this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1255');

function heb($phrase){
    static $lang = array(
        'title' => 'ודים אילוף כלבים',
    );
    return $lang[$phrase];
}

?>
```

and my index.php file is like this:

```
<?php
include('langs.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255" />
        <title><?php echo heb('title'); ?></title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    </head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

but the title is "׳•׳“׳™׳ ׳׳™׳׳•׳£ ׳›׳׳‘׳™׳", and not the word in hebrew - what can I do to edit the lang file in Hebrew without getting a wrong encoding?

Answer (score 2):

The `Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1255` and related meta tag is just an *indicator* to the browser that the site is supposedly encoded in Windows-1255; it just tells the browser what to expect. If the *actual content* is not actually encoded in Windows-1255, then you'll of course get wrong results.

In PHP, string literals have the encoding of the source file they're saved in. I.e.:

```
'title' => 'ודים אילוף כלבים'
```

This string is encoded in whatever encoding the file it's written in is encoded in. I'll guess that your editor saved the file as UTF-8. So you're actually sending UTF-8 content to the browser, but are telling it that it's Windows-1255 encoded. Hence: garbage characters.

Either actually save your PHP file in Windows-1255 or set the encoding indicators to (I'm guessing) UTF-8 instead.

Comment: also the `static $lang = array ..` syntax is wrong. (or am I missing something?)

Comment: Yeah I see, sorry :).. `static $a = array(` is possible while `static $a = time();` (for example) isn't. didn't know that ...